# can't able to handle UIActions from subclasses

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performselector

I am creating a class for soap webservice to get some information from .net webserver.

for that i am using `NSMutableURLRequest` and parse the result using `NSXmlParser`.

Now i am calling that web services class from myviewcontroller.m class like this.

```
    mywebserviceClass *obj=[[mywebserviceClass alloc] init];
[obj mymethod];
```

i am adding result to an array to use that array details in myviewcontroller.m class.

but i did n't get details into array while i am using that array immediately after this method.

i am trying like this by calling another method after 2 sec to use that array like this.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myanotherMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

i know the reason why it is, it takes time to parse.

I am trying another way like i am creating object for viewcontroller and call this method  like this.

```
myviewcontroller *obj=[[myviewcontroller alloc] init];
[obj myanothermethod];
```

NOw i can able to get details but i can't able to handle UIActivities like raising alerts.

While as told in the above `performSelector` method i can able to handle all UIActivities.

But i need to call that method after completion of parsing of result.

Can any one please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Call your web service in `viewDidLoad/ViewWillAppear` methods of UIViewController. Collect your data and then call Parse method like- `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(methodName) waitUntilDone:YES];` Below that use your array to display view or if you are displaying in table view then just call `[mytblviewobj reloadData];`